¿Por qué tengo un stack smashing?
Edit: subí mi codigo a github, este es el link: https://github.com/nicochare/simPeaje
tengo un problema con un algoritmo que estoy creando para una tarea.
El algoritmo simula el paso de automóviles por un peaje de 5 cabinas por 3 horas.
Esta es la salida del programa en consola:
asd@asd:/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/pr6$ make sim
./simPeaje
Introduzca el tiempo medio de llegadas (en segundos): 12
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
make: *** [makefile:8: sim] Aborted

Creo que agregué todo el código necesario para enviar el contexto, de no ser así por favor comentamelo.
Este es el codigo:
Definicion de los tipos utilizados en el código de abajo:
typedef struct nodoDeColaDeEnteros {
    int e;
    struct nodoDeColaDeEnteros *s;
} NodoDeColaDeEnteros;

typedef struct colaDeEnteros {
    NodoDeColaDeEnteros *i;
    NodoDeColaDeEnteros *f;
} ColaDeEnteros;

typedef struct cabina {
    int nCoches; // coches esperando en la cabina
    int maxCoches; // maximo de coches esperando
    int servidos; // coches servidos
    int totalEsperado; // tiempo total de esperas
    int proxServ; // instante proximo servicio
    int minServ; // tiempo minimo del servicio
    int maxServ; // tiempo maximo del servicio
    ColaDeEnteros colaCoches; // cola de coches
} Cabina;

#define NCAB 5
typedef Cabina Peaje[NCAB];

typedef int Reloj;

typedef struct frecuencia {
    int tLlegada;
    int tMedio;
} Frecuencia;

typedef struct control {
    Peaje peaje;
    Frecuencia trafico;
} Control;

typedef struct intervalo {
    int min;
    int max;
} Intervalo;

Intervalo tipoCobro[] = { {15,30}, {15,30}, {15,45}, {15,45}, {30,60} };

simPeaje.c (programa principal)
#include "modulos/controles.h"

// tiempo para la simulacion 3 horas (10800 segundos)
#define TSIM 10800

void iniciarSimulacion(Control *c) {
    iniciarRuleta();
    iniciarControl(c);
}

void siguienteIteracion(Control *c, Reloj r) {
    llegaCoche(c, r);
    marchaCoche(c, r);
}

void mostrarResultados(Control c) {
    printf("Resultados");
}

int main() {
    Reloj r;
    Control c;
    
    aCero(&r);
    iniciarSimulacion(&c);

    while (instante(r) != TSIM) {
        tic(&r);
        siguienteIteracion(&c, r);
    }

    mostrarResultados(c);
    return 0;
}

iniciarControl en control.c
void iniciarControl(Control *c) {
    int tiempo;
    printf("Introduzca el tiempo medio de llegadas (en segundos): ");
    scanf("%d", &tiempo);
    while (tiempo <= 0) {
        printf("\nError, por favor ingrese un tiempo mayor a 0.\nIntroduzca el tiempo medio de llegadas (en segundos): ");
        scanf("%d", &tiempo);
    }
    c->trafico.tMedio = tiempo;
    c->trafico.tLlegada = distribucionExponencial(c->trafico.tMedio);
    iniciarPeaje(&c->peaje);
}

distribucionExponencial en ruleta.c
int distribucionExponencial(int media) {
    int t;
    float x;
    x = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; // num aleatorio entre [0,1)
    t = (int)( -log(1-x) * media);
    while (t == 0) {
        x = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX; // num aleatorio entre [0,1)
        t = (int)( -log(1-x) * media);
    }
    return t;
}

iniciarPeaje en peajes.c
void iniciarPeaje(Peaje *p) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NCAB; i++) {
        iniciarCab(p[i], tipoCobro[i].min, tipoCobro[i].max);
    }
}

iniciarCab en cabina.c
void iniciarCab(Cabina *cab, int tmin, int tmax) {
    cab->nCoches = 0;
    cab->maxCoches = 0;
    cab->servidos = 0;
    cab->totalEsperado = 0;
    cab->proxServ = 0;
    cab->minServ = tmin;
    cab->maxServ = tmax;
    nuevaColaDeEnteros(&cab->colaCoches);
}

nuevaColaDeEnteros en colaDeEnteros.c (Implementacion dinamica con punteros
void nuevaColaDeEnteros(ColaDeEnteros *c) {
    c->i = NULL;
    c->f = NULL;
}


El mensaje de smashing the stack se genera al salir de una función cuando el canario que se pone en la pila ha sido modificado. Eso ocurre cuando se produce un buffer overflow de alguna variable local. En las funciones que incluyes no veo ningún buffer en ninguna función y ninguna escritura. Lo más sencillo es que compiles tu programa con información de debug y lo ejecutes en un depurador para ver donde se produce el buffer overflow. Así sabrás que función genera el error. A primera vista no parece que el problema esté en ninguna de estas funciones.

@RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor Gracias por tu respuesta. Utilizando el gdb -tui descubrí que por alguna razon los valores tLlegada y tMedio del atributo trafico de tipo Frecuencia, de la variable c de tipo Control que se utiliza en el main() vuelven de la funcion iniciarSimulacion() con un valor 0, aunque dentro de la misma tengan otros valores. Aún así no entiendo por qué pasa esto

Al pasar por la línea de iniciarPeaje(&c->peaje); en la funcion de iniciarControl(...) se borran los valores calculados en las lineas previas

Cambia en iniciarPeaje a iniciarCab(&((*p)[i]),.... Estás pasando un puntero a Peaje que se puede interpretar como un array de Peajes. Si no lo dereferencias estarías accediendo a Peaje[NCAB*i]... La definición del tipo Peaje es peliaguda y debes tener cuidado al usarla. Quizás deberías considerar cambiarla. De todas formas, con el código que has proporcionado no puedo reproducir el overflow así que no estoy seguro de si este error es el causante de tu prolema original.

Muchas gracias, esto solucionó el problema del paso por referencia del atributo peaje de la variable "c", pero aún así no logro entender si es un error mío de lógica o un error mío de código.
Ingresando 12 en el tiempo medio de llegadas obtengo luego de varias ejecuciones con la misma entrada:

Primero en cola nula (funcion de error para evitar accesos absurdos a memoria)
Segmentation Fault
stack smashing


Hola nicochare. Puedes generar un único fichero .c con el código minimo neccesario para reproducir tu problema?. El código que has incluído no se puede compilar. También puedes intentar lo que te comenté en el primer mensaje. Ejecuta el programa en gdb y cuando falle vuelca la pila usando el comando bt, eso te mostrará información sobre donde está el problema. (desactiva la proteccion del pila con el flag gcc -fno-stack-protector

He realizado dos cambios en tu código y al menos ahora no se estrella si bien no se si funciona correctamente. Estos son los cambios:
modulo/peaje.c

void ordenar(taux *t1) {
    // tamaño maximo tabla = NCAB
    int i, j ;
    Pareja *t = (Pareja *)*t1;
    for (i = 0; i < NCAB-1; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < NCAB; j++) {
            if (t[i].can > t[j].can) {
                intercambio(&t[i], &t[j]);
        }
        }
    }
}

void guardaCola(Peaje *p, int ncab, Reloj r) {
    encolarCoche(&(*p)[ncab], r);
}

void rondaCabinas(Peaje *p, Reloj r) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NCAB; i++) {
        servCabina(&(*p)[i], r);
    }
}

La función intercambio parece funcionar, pero deberías usar memset en lugar de asignar punteros en ese caso, ya que tu tipo taux es un array estático de estructuras Pareja no de punteros a estructuras Pareja
void intercambio(Pareja *a, Pareja *b) {
    Pareja aux;

    memcpy (&aux, a, sizeof(Pareja));
    memcpy (a, b, sizeof(Pareja));
    memcpy (b, &aux, sizeof(Pareja));

}

Es mejor definir todas tus estructuras dinámicamente y solo usar punteros de esa forma te aseguras que las entradas de tus arrays son punteros y los puedes intercambiar de forma segura como en tu implementación de intercambio.
Como puedes ver en ambos casos tienes problemas con las estructuras que has definido como typedef de arrays:
typedef Cabina Peaje[NCAB];
typedef Pareja taux[NCAB];

Mi consejo es que elimines esas estructuras y que utilices punteros/arrays a Cabina y Pareja según necesites de forma que no tendrás que dereferenciar punteros de forma extraña.
Por otra parte si creas tus estructuras dinámicamente obtines de forma natural todos los punteros que necesitas y todo tu código funcionaría usando punteros. Por ejemplo:
typedef struct control {
   Cabina     *peaje[NCAB];
   Frecuencia trafico;
} Control;

// Inicializacion
c = malloc (sizeof(Control));

for (int i = 0; i < NCAB; i++) c->peaje[i] = malloc (sizeof(Cabina));

De esta forma, todos tus campos son punteros y los puedes pasar directamente sin tener que usar el operador &.
Espero que esto te ayude
P.S.: Igual así es como está implementado el programa (veo que el proyecto de github no está completo), pero por si acaso no es el caso y a no ser que tengas otras limitaciones, yo consideraría implementar esto como un simulador de eventos discretos

Muchas gracias! esto lo solucionó, cambiando los elementos de un array pasados por referencia como &(*p)[ncab]
